# Unable to clone Windows 10 image from 1TB HDD to 500 GB SSD

Tags: windows-10, restore, clone

I am replacing 1TB HDD on my laptop with 500GB SSD. The C drive (with Windows 10 OS) on HDD is of **119GB**. The image of the OS - with all customizations, software and files - that I have created on an external HDD is of **76GB**. I have tried restoring the image on to the SSD:

- As one single partition or creating a new partition of 120 GB.
- Restore image using Windows 10 bootable USB as well as CD.
- Restore image using Windows 10 recovery USB as well as CD.
- Restore image from bare Windows 10 OS freshly installed on SSD.

In all the cases, the error message displayd is:

> Error: The disk that is set as active in BIOS is too small to recover
>   the original system disk......

I thought if cloning the image by inserting the SSD in an external casing (I've tried two different ones from a local market) using software available for the purpose. But the laptop or the OS are not able to detect SSD from the casing. Not even in Disk Management. They are detecting HDD only.

Is there any workaround or hack to clone the image on the SSD?

Regards

Comment: Please help us help you by providing more info. Run _diskpart_ after opening a Command Prompt window as Administrator (Start | Windows System | right-click on Command Prompt | More | Run as administrator). In _diskpart_ do _list disk_ , _sel disk 0_, then _list part_. Copy the result into Notepad, then do _sel disk 1_ then _list part_ again. Copy that result and save it to Notepad as well. Close w/ _exit_ twice, come back here, click on [edit] and paste what you found into your question. More details on _diskpart_ at https://ss64.com/nt/diskpart.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskpart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several software and work arounds, Mini Tools Partition Wizard Free Edition did the job.

Here's the [link](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html). It has easy to follow instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I had shrunk the partition with Windows Disk Management,
moved the partitions with GParted and checked it booted. 
sfdisk in Clonezilla gave error that last LBA specified by script was out of range.
I had `sdb` as the source disk and `sdc` as the destination.

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sdb >b.parts
```

and

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sdc >c.parts
```

I made the last-lba in `b.parts` equal to the last-lba in `c.parts` and
then

```
sfdisk /dev/sdc <b.parts
```

then ran Clonezilla and told it not to create the partitions.
That worked fine for me. I hope this helps someone else.